# How to say a fact in general?

Tags: articles, definite-article, singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article, zero-article

When you want to talk about cheetahs in general,

1. A cheetah can run fast.
2. The cheetah can run fast.
3. Cheetahs can run fast.
4. The cheetahs can run fast.

are they all correct?  Which one would you use in a daily conversation and which one in an official document?

Comment: The duplicate goes into a lot of detail, but a short answer is "Cheetahs can run fast" is simple correct and formal. It would be used in both conversation and an official document.  But read the duplicate for a lot more detail.

Comment: (4) is the only one which _can't_ refer to cheetahs in general; it would have to be a reference to a particular group of them.